# The method `pd.groupby.GroupBy.prod()` is not implemented yet

Tags: python, pandas, database, databricks, spark-koalas

I have a database with two columns: name (str) and probability (float).

I am running this command:

```
df[['name','probability']].groupby('name').prod()
```

on a Databricks (runtime 7.3) notebook and df is a pyspark.pandas dataframe.

The error I get is:

```
PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.groupby.GroupBy.prod()` is not implemented yet.
```

I wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: check with this df[['name','probability']].groupby('name') is the type is pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy or else you want to change version

Comment: I have version 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think your mistake is simply the fact that you have not the latest versions of pandas installed. From what I can see V.1.5.2, has such function in its documentation, and when I tried to run such group by on a sample data I succeeded. Try running this command on your shell that oughta upgrade your pandas version and you are gonna able to run such function.

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

check with this `type(df[['name','probability']].groupby('name'))` is the type is `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy` or else you want to update version

Comment: Results is  pyspark.pandas.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy

Comment: then you want to install - pip install pandas
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177467/databricks-pyspark-vs-pandas